# Understanding Linux source address selection

Tags: linux, networking

I have a Linux server with 2 IP addresses on it. One is a ULA(fd00::/8) and the other is a GUA(2000::/3) both are assigned to the loopback interface. My routing table contains `src` attributes on routes to explicitly force Linux to pick a particular address for a particular destination, despite this and despite the standard address labeling which should cause the ULA to be used when the destination is a ULA and the GUA to be used when the destination is a GUA that does not happen. If I run `ip r g` I get a different `src` than if I run `ip r` even though there's only a single route in the routing table that matches the given prefix. Additionally this behavior is not stable, Linux will randomly flip between the right and wrong source addresses which leads to connectivity being hit or miss.

```
root@ninym:~# ip r g fd2e:9fea:c7ed:53::
fd2e:9fea:c7ed:53:: from :: via fe80::60:1 dev eth0 proto bgp src 2001:db8:60:2:: metric 20 pref medium
root@ninym:~# ip r | grep ^fd2e:9fea:c7ed:53::
fd2e:9fea:c7ed:53::/64 nhid 6 via fe80::60:1 dev eth0 proto bgp src fd2e:9fea:c7ed:6002:: metric 20 pref medium
```

EDIT: So these routes are coming from frr via BGP and I have the following route-map. Disabling this route-map fixes the problem although it's not ideal. This is set because some of my servers have multiple ULAs and this allows me to insure the right one is always being selected. I can disable it on this server as this server doesn't have multiples but it affects all my servers, just some more than others. I'm not sure if this is an frr bug or if I'm doing something wrong with my route-map

```
route-map src_map permit 10
 match ipv6 address gua
 set src 2001:db8:60:12::
exit
!
route-map src_map permit 20
 match ipv6 address ula
 set src fd2e:9fea:c7ed:6012::
exit
```